# How to run knockd with Debian 9 on system boot?

Tags: linux, debian, systemd

I've installed knockd via APT, configured it in **/etc/knockd.conf** and enabled it in **/etc/default/knockd**. However, it does not start when I reboot the system. Starting up manually works just fine.

I tried to enable it:

```
# systemctl enable knockd.service
```

But it fails, because **knockd.service** is missing an [Install] section. Is it safe to let systemd start knockd by simply adding that section to the service file? Is it even meant to be started that way?

On Arch Linux knockd comes with an [Install] section in the service file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's safe to add it. Looks like it's error in service file. I've opened [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=868015) in Debian bugtracker.